# The system cannot find the file specified while programming C

Tags: c, visual-studio, compiler-errors, runtime-error

Ok so I'm using Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10. I'm wanting to use it to program in C. When I tried making a program, I got this one error "Unable to start program 'C:\Users\XXXX\source\repos\TestingProject\Debug\TestingProject.exe'. The system cannot find the file specified."
I looked around, and some people said it's due to faulty code that should bring up errors while compiling. There were a few issues, and I solved them to the best of my ability, but still can't get it to run. Since I can't figure out how to get Visual Studio to tell me specifically what's wrong (maybe if someone could tell me how I could get Visual Studio to say underline what piece of code doesn't make sense) I instead tried making and running a simple hello world program. However, I still got the error.

Here's the Hello World program code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World! This is Just a test.");
    return 0;
}
```

It still gives me that one error, and I don't know how to fix it. Also, if someone could tell me how to make Visual Studio do error checks while writing code, please tell me how. If anyone can help, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: There is nithing wrong with uyour program. The error message is likely a result of some misconfiguration. Try to create a fresh project without modifying any settings.

Comment: Did that, multiple times. Still doesn't work. I've tried reinstalling it once, and it won't work.

Comment: Do you have an antivirus? Try to disable it temporarily and build and run the program again.

Comment: Tried that, still nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the whole issue was down to the C file not actually being inside the project itself. This is quickly solved by looking at where the file is located by looking at the properties window, then locating the file, followed by copying the file and pasting it inside the "Solution Explorer" window.

Now, it actually shows me the error checks and what errors the code has. When I now create a "Hello World" program, it opens a separate window and prints out "Hello World!".

I must've thought that since I had the project open, and then opening a file from my desktop, that it could run perfectly fine. Just need to keep this in mind next time.

Answer (score 0):

You can always try File -> Move .cpp into -> then select your project folder.

This worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

You can always try File -> Move .cpp into -> then select your project folder.